# Uploading and Processing a CSV File using Bottle; Possible Encoding Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, bottle

I am trying to upload and process a CSV file via an HTML form using Bottle. I've already created a working example with Tkinter; the CSV uploads nicely and all data, including the hashed passwords get into the Sqlite3 database.

**WORKING TKINTER CODE ...**

```
import os
import sqlite3
import csv
from pbkdf2 import crypt
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

def open1():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    with open(filename,"r") as s_info:
        reader = csv.reader(s_info)
        for x in reader:
            pwhash = crypt(x[1])
            connection = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
            cursor_v = connection.cursor()
            cursor_v.execute("insert into users (cemail, cpassword) values (?,?)", (x[0],pwhash))
            connection.commit()
            cursor_v.close()
        else:
            print("CSV Uploaded")

x = Button(text="Open",command=open1).pack()
```

The issue is when I try to re-create the the code in Bottle, I get the following error:

**BOTTLE CODE - HTML:**

```
<form action="/panel" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="data" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**BOTTLE CODE - ROUTE:**

```
@route('/panel', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    data = request.files.data
    with open(data,"r") as s_info:
        reader = csv.reader(s_info)
        for x in reader:
            pwhash = crypt(x[1])
            connection = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
            cursor_v = connection.cursor()
            cursor_v.execute("insert into users (cemail, cpassword) values (?,?)", (x[0],pwhash))
            connection.commit()
            cursor_v.close()
        else:
            return "<p>CSV Uploaded</p>"
```

**ERROR:**

```
with open(data,"r") as s_info:
TypeError: invalid file: <bottle.FileUpload object at 0x105cb84d0>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.files.data` is a [`FileUpload`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.FileUpload) object. It has an attribute named `file`, so:

**EDIT**: Updated to handle byte streams given by `urllib` with python-3.x.

```
import codecs

def do_upload():
    reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(request.files.data.file, 'utf-8'))
    for x in reader:
        ...
```

should work, making your bottle code look like this:

```
import codecs

@route('/panel', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(request.files.data.file, 'utf-8'))
    for x in reader:
        pwhash = crypt(x[1])
        connection = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
        cursor_v = connection.cursor()
        cursor_v.execute("insert into users (cemail, cpassword) values (?,?)", (x[0],pwhash))
        connection.commit()
        cursor_v.close()
    else:
        return "<p>CSV Uploaded</p>"
```

Comment: Hi totoro. Thank you for your help. I'm getting this error now ...     for x in reader:... _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: @VictorEliasRodriguez Yes, you have a Python 3.x issue where `urllib` returns bytes and `csv` expects strings. So the bytes need to be converted into string form by specifying the codec. I have updated my answer.